# Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[FilterOptionsComponent -> Environment]:

Tags: angular, testing

I am trying to test my app but i have the next error:
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) FilterOptionsComponent should clean fields when click in the clean button FAILED
    Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[FilterOptionsComponent -> Environment]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FilterOptionsComponent -> Environment]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for Environment! in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js (line 34858)

And i dont know what is going on.

I tried to build again.

Comment: Please add a code

Comment: You must add a portion of your test. Most probably you are using a service in your component which is not added in the providers of the TestModule

Answer (score 0):

As possible solution, you can provide environment to your test. Not having your code, it's hard to tell exactly how to modify it; in my example, it looks like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: "environment", useValue: {} },
  ],
})
```